# How to reload page without resetting $_SESSION?

Tags: javascript, php, session

How can I reload a page without resetting the data stored in $_SESSION? I'm making AI for a Tic Tac Toe game, and when the AI chooses its move I need the page to update so the character can be placed on the board.

```
echo "<script>location.reload(true);</script>";
```

causes $_SESSION to be reset, it seems.

Comment: No that wont cause session to reset, unless you have sessions misconfiguration, Likely have php that is overwritting the data - please show the php related to session

Comment: if session already exists, dont do what every your doing to 'reset' it

Comment: Save the session id in a cookie or post it with a form to itself instead of using location.reload.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but you actually ask one question in the topic and a total oposite in first sentence.

Comment: Have you remembered to make a session_start() on top of every php script you use.